# Fechas y días en PHP

Tags: php

Tengo un arreglo que tiene ciertos días de despacho:

```
$despacho = array("Lunes","Viernes","Sabado");
```

Los despachos se hacen en 2 días hábiles después del pedido. Si yo lo pido el lunes debería llegarme el miércoles, pero como el miércoles no está en el array, fechas de despachos deberá llegarme el día más cercano a esa fecha: viernes.

Otro ejemplo: si pido un sábado deberá llegarme el lunes y como está en la lista se puede entregar.

```
$dias = array("Domingo","Lunes","Martes","Miercoles","Jueves","Viernes","Sabado");
        $meses = array("Enero","Febrero","Marzo","Abril","Mayo","Junio","Julio","Agosto","Septiembre","Octubre","Noviembre","Diciembre");

    $despacho = array("Lunes","Viernes","Sabado");
    $dia_actual = $dias[date('w')];
    $dia_actual_normal = $dias[date('w')+2];
    if(in_array($dia_actual_normal,$despacho))
        {
            $actual = $dia_actual_normal;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Esto va a depender mucho de cómo quieras implementarlo. Podrías crear una función que pasado el día que se hizo el pedido te devuelva el día que se hará el despacho:

```
function devuelveDiaDespacho($dia) {
    switch ($dia) {
        case "Domingo":   return "Viernes";
        case "Lunes":     return "Viernes";
        case "Martes":    return "Viernes";
        case "Miercoles": return "Viernes";
        case "Jueves":    return "Sabado";
        case "Viernes":   return "Lunes";
        case "Sabado":    return "Lunes";
    }
}

$dias = array("Domingo","Lunes","Martes","Miercoles","Jueves","Viernes","Sabado");
$dia_actual = $dias[date('w')];

$actual = devuelveDiaDespacho($dia_actual);
```

Podrías crear un array asociativo (ya que serían sólo 7 elementos) y simplemente devolver basándote en el índice:

```
$dias = array("Domingo","Lunes","Martes","Miercoles","Jueves","Viernes","Sabado");
$dias_despacho = array(
    "Domingo"   => "Viernes",
    "Lunes"     => "Viernes",
    "Martes"    => "Viernes",
    "Miercoles" => "Viernes",
    "Jueves"    => "Sabado",
    "Viernes"   => "Lunes",
    "Sabado"    => "Lunes"
);

$dia_actual = $dias[date('w')];
$actual = $dias_despacho[$dia_actual];
```

Podrías hacer una combinación de los dos... como decía, al final va a depender mucho de cómo quieras implementarlo.

Comment: Esos ejemplos estan bien pero solo hace que le sume dos dias al dia actual osea si es miercoles es el viernes pero  tengo un array por ejemplo $dias = array ('lunes','martes','sabado');  si yo pido un martes al sumarle dos dias me llega el jueves pero como el dia jueves no esta en mi array debe entrgar el dia mas cercano del martes sefgun el array osea el sabado se entiende ?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
  $hoy = time();       // la fecha de hoy o la que corresponda a la compra
  $dias_despacho = 2;  // los dias minimos de despacho
  $despacho = $hoy + ( 86400 * $dias_despacho ); // el dia minimo de
                                                 // despacho
                                                 // los segundos del dia
                                                 // 86400 => ( 60*60*24 )
  for(;;)  // busca el dia que se puede despachar
  {
    if ( is_despachable( $despacho ) ) // aca pones la logica segun la comuna
                                       // si es feriado, hay muchos despachos
                                       //  o lo que sea
    {
        echo 'se va a despachar el ' . date( 'r', $despacho );
        break;
    }
    // no era despachable ese dia
    // vemos si el siguiente
    $despacho += ( 86400 );
  }

  function is_despachable( $fecha ){
     return true;  // aca pones la logica
  }
```